# How can i match this expression, and remove the last word?

Tags: regex

```
Update: XAUUSD LONG
100pip classic
Locked riskfree
```

```
/\bUpdate\b.*\b(short|long)\b/gi
```

Gives me:

```
100pip classic
Locked riskfree
```

I want:

```
Update: XAUUSD
100pip classic
Locked riskfree
```

Basically want to remove the word `long` or `short` if `Update: XAUUSD` exists.

Comment: You say you want to remove the last word, while your example says otherwise.

Comment: I want to remove the last word in the first line that contains "update" and "long OR short"

Answer (score 2):

You can switch the capture groups capturing the first part instead. In the replacement use capture group 1.

Using a case insensitive match:

```
\b(Update\b.*)\b(?:short|long)\b
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/6mrXCy/1).

Comment: I love the internet and all you fabulous people. Thank you kindly. You made my day. 

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the first line is the only one that matters. You also didn't mention what language you're using - is it just in a text editor?

You can replace this pattern (case insensitive) to an empty string:

```
(?<=update:\s*xauusd) (short|long)\b
```

It uses a positive lookbehind.